# Function imported from .net assembly always returns true on windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, import, boolean

I'm importing functions into my code at runtime from a .net dll I compiled on windows 7 64bit.

Pseudo:

```
delegate bool Test(int i);

var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(...);
var type = assembly.GetType(...);
var method = type.GetMethod(...);
Test test = (Test) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Test), method);
```

Now, when I call the imported function on windows 7 (which I compiled everything on) it works like it is supposed to, however, when I call it on windows 8 (64bit) it always returns true, even if the only thing the function does is "return false". In both cases, the function seems to be imported correctly. I checked with

```
Console.WriteLine(test.Method.ToString());
```

And it does output the function's name and type.

Any ideas what might be causing it?

Edit:

Ok here's the code. Still shortened and simplified, but without anything important cut out.

The dll code:

```
namespace InputController_Scripts
{
    class script
    {
        public static bool Test_Paused(int color)
        {
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
```

The program's code:

```
delegate bool DTest(int color);

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom($@"{extraPath}{Config.GameName.ToLower()}.dll");
Type type = assembly.GetType("InputController_Scripts.script");
MethodInfo mInfo = type.GetMethod("Test_Paused");
DTest test = (DTest)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(DTest), mInfo);

Console.WriteLine(test(123)); //false on win7, true on win8
```

**Edit:**

Ok, I found the problem. It wasn't to do with reflection (sorry, guys, yes, I was wrong about "not cutting out anything important"). Long story short, windows 8 had different regional setting and "0,10" in a config file was interpreted like "10" which was messing everything up. I changed it to "0.10" and now it works.

Comment: The problem is your code. If there were an issue that all reflected `bool` delegates would return `true` and `true only` on Windows 8, lots of existing code would be broken on many machines. Show your actual code.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't believe it. Are you sure you're loading the correct assembly, and not another version that does return `true`?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. I'm thinking about recompiling the dll on windows 8, perhaps that could help.

Comment: @Swift: Try recompiling the DLL on Windows 7 like you normally would, but change the code to throw an exception instead of returning `false`. If the code on Windows 8 still produces a `true` value, I think that's a strong indicator that it's not calling the method you think it is, or not pointing to the right DLL, or maybe somehow else using the wrong DLL (is it possible that maybe an old version of the assembly is already loaded into memory?)

Comment: @Swift: You can also try changing the signature of the method (or remove it completely) If your Windows 8 code is still finding and invoking the method, you know for sure that the correct DLL isn't being loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions, but I was wrong thinking that it had to do with that. Updated the op.